# Append "prefix text" in associative arrays key => value at the begining of the value

Tags: php, associative-array

im fetching a API in json format and when i json_decode it becomes associative array. 
now in array i want to append http://test.com?link= on every specific key value and append it from the beginning of the value so that it will be clickable link 
because the link provided in actual API json format https://download.com/x.zip  is BLOCKED by my ISP so i made proxy server to take the request from client and download the file from API server and send back to the client 
for that i have to add my PROXY server address on every link in Array value

**this is what i get from array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Movie Name] => Avatar
            [Zip Download] => https://download.com/1.zip
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Movie Name] => "Avatar: The Last             
        [Zip Download] => https://download.com/2.zip
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Movie Name] => Avatar            
        [Zip Download] => https://download.com/3.zip
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Movie Name] => Avatar
        [Zip Download] => https://download.com/4.zip
    )
```

)

**and this is what i want to do and i will encode it back to json**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Movie Name] => Avatar
            [Zip Download] => http://test.com?link=https://download.com/1.zip
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Movie Name] => "Avatar: The Last             
        [Zip Download] => http://test.com?link=https://download.com/2.zip
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Movie Name] => Avatar            
        [Zip Download] => http://test.com?link=https://download.com/3.zip
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Movie Name] => Avatar
        [Zip Download] => http://test.com?link=https://download.com/4.zip
    )
```

)

Comment: Have you tried anything at all or want us to write the code for you?

Comment: Please don’t post “I want” questions that lack any clear description of what your problem was with _getting_ to where you want. Show us what you tried! Go read [ask] in general, please.

Comment: @pr1nc3
i tried many ways to just append some text on the value but i couldn't make it 
either it goes on the last of array or creates new array index => value

Comment: Then show us some code of what you tried and did not work so we can help you debug your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that should do it

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'name' => 'Avatar: The Last',
        'zip' => 'https://download.com/2.zip'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Avatar',
        'zip' => 'https://download.com/3.zip'
    ]
];

$array = array_map(function ($item) {
    $item['zip'] = 'http://test.com?link=' . $item['zip'];
    return $item;
}, $array);



var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Wow you just solved it within minutes and i was banging my head from 3days really

Answer (score 1):

It is done with array_map();

```
$array = array_map(function($value){ return 'prefix'.$value; }, $array);
```

transforms

```
1 2 3
```

to

```
prefix1 prefix2 prefix3
```